# IgnoreDataMember attribute on MetaData class doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, attributes

I am using entity framework v6.0 DB first.

I have a problem where a certain class breaks on serialization due to a certain navigation property.

When I'm adding to the auto generated cs class the attribute ***IgnoreDataMember*** everything works as expected (serialization passes), but I cannot leave it there of course because next time someone generate the scripts it will disappear so I've created MetaData class like the following and it just not working. (the serialization still breaks)

Metadata:

```
public class SomeClassMetaData
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<SomeFoo> FOO { get; set; }
}
```

Partial (non auto generated) class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(SomeClassMetaData))]
public partial class SomeClass
{

}
```

Partial (auto generated) part of class:

```
public virtual ICollection<SomeFoo> FOO { get; set; }
```

I've checked:

- Partial class has same name
- Same namespace
- Both partial public
- Opening model browser and saving.

No idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly [IgnoreDataMember] doesn't work with EF6 proxy objects. Metadatatype only works with DataAnnotations. Doesn't work for serialization. Must be specified directly on the properties in entity. If you use T4 template for class generation, you may want to add some logic to create these attributes directly in the template. The feature you should consider to do this is called 'Structural annotation'. Check this link for more information.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/efdesign/2008/08/12/structural-annotations-one-pager/

Comment: Thanks :( I'll look into that... any other option maybe?

Comment: An alternative option is to map entity models to view models that exclude the property and then serialize the view models.  However, I am not sure this is an improvement over structural annotations.

Answer (score 0):

According to Raj's answer this cannot be done.

Workaround that I did was selecting this table without that navigation property. 
(In my case we use oData so just using $select to all the columns except this one.)